# disable/change access keys for wikipedia

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, wikipedia, firefox

As I stumbled upon an add-on to control the Spotify web player from a keyboard, I noticed that sites like Wikipedia are using so-called [access keys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_key) to up/downgrade users experience. That is alright until I can not find a way to block specified access keys from websites or even change them. 
In Firefox <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> seem to activate those access keys. Hence <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> is my desired shortcut to stop and play the music within the web player, but is conflicting with the same short cut on wikipedia.com

Is there any way to permit or change access keys from specified websites for good? I don't have much understanding, but cookies won't be the solution since they are cleared on a regular basis.

PS: I very much prefer a solution without extensions

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/168087/how-to-forbid-keyboard-shortcut-stealing-by-websites-in-firefox

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5637530/disable-shortcuts-in-google-chrome

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20372394/how-to-disable-ctrlu-using-javascript

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/168087/how-to-forbid-keyboard-shortcut-stealing-by-websites-in-firefox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better late than never: I've found the first linked [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/168087/how-to-forbid-keyboard-shortcut-stealing-by-websites-in-firefox) of @user0 with its instructions very helpful.

Go to "site informations" next to the URL, expand "Connections details" and hit "More informations". A small window "site informations" will pop up, under "Permissions" uncheck "override shrotcuts".*

*Losely translated into english since my language setting is different.